# Red5 cutting streams

Tags: red5

I have a flex app that was developed using wowza as media server. The purpose of the app is to record the microphone of the client. I have to switch over to red5 now, and so I set up a VM with red5. I had success in creating streams, but only a small part of the audio is saved correctly on the flv files under the stream/ folders. Why is that happening? Could anybody point me out some suggestions, as I am aware only of the possibility to rewrite extending RTMPClient instead of using  NetStream and NetConnection.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the version of Red5.

Are/were you using Red5 version 1.0 ? There is a bug in that which truncates a lot from both ends in the final .flv.

You could downgrade to a lower version or use 1.0.2. It works fine in these.